# How do I create a subset data frame, filtering statistical units based on value of a certain variable?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a subset data frame, that only includes countries (my statistical unit) that have a population of greater than 10million. Essentially trying to filter out units based on their value of a particular variable? Any input would be great.

I.e.

```
dat2 <- na.omit(subset(world.data, select=c("year","countrycode",
                                            "ctryname","eg_use_elec_kh_pc","sp_urb_totl_in_zs")))
```

is what i use to eliminate variables but not sure how to filter the units using conditions or parameters.

Thank you for your efforts. I apologize if this questions been asked previously. As I'm new to R and statistical analysis, phrasing my questions properly, as well as understanding previously asked questions, can be a bit difficult.

Comment: try `dat2 <- na.omit(subset(world.data, population > 10e6, select=c("year","countrycode","ctryname","eg_use_elec_kh_pc","sp_urb_totl_in_zs")))` where `population` is the column name containing the population in your `world.data` data.frame

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked without error.